# How to replace letters in a cell with defined numbers from a separate table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a cell which is has mixed numbers and letters(ex. `AA12CC45WR`) and they are random.

On another sheet, I have a table which has the equivalent for each letter like (cells `A1`, `B1`)

```
A=1
C=25
W=66
R=77
```

for the ABC letters until Z

The solution should be `11122525456677`

How do I generate a function to replace all the letters with the defined numbers in the other sheet?

Comment: Is the text to be decoded always 10 characters?

Comment: Does `A1` contain `1` or the string `A=1`?

Comment: usually the text will be 22 digits

Comment: For more clarification cell A1: contains A and cell B1 contains the value which is 1

Comment: Are you open to using a custom VBA function?

Comment: yes, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will do the decoding. Place this in a module and update the Range reference as necessary.  If cell `A1` has original "code" value, enter the formula: `=Decode(A1)` in another cell to get the "decoded" value.

```
Public Function Decode(Code As String) As String
    Dim iIdx As Integer
    Dim sChar As String
    Dim sResult As String
    For iIdx = 1 To Len(Code)
        sChar = UCase$(Mid$(Code, iIdx, 1))
        If Asc(sChar) >= 65 And Asc(sChar) <= 90 Then
            sChar = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sChar, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B26"), 2, False)
        End If
        sResult = sResult & sChar
    Next iIdx
    Decode = sResult
End Function
```

Comment: Where should I place it?

Comment: Put the code in a regular module (not a class module that is tied to a sheet)--go to the VB Editor, Insert menu, and click Module.

Answer (score 0):

If of interest today (2020):

If desired, a formula that will do it:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,VLOOKUP(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),$F$1:$G$36,2,FALSE))
```

It assumes the input value is in A1, and uses a lookup table with two columns, the left one having TEXT characters from 0-9 then A-Z (36 rows) and to begin, the formula =F_ in the rightmost column cells. Those would be replaced with the values for the letters (though presumably the 0-9 entries would not) as one defined them (immediately for all, or over time a couple now, a couple then, so any letter not assigned a numerical value would simply replace itself. That table is F1:G36.

Modify the source and lookup table addresses as desired.

Using `TEXTJOIN()` also allows placing a delimiter (perhaps a hyphen) between values for each original character, if ever desired. Other methods of concatenating/joing them back together have a harder time with that.

In 2011, one would have used `CONCATENATE() or union-ing with`ROW()`in place of`SEQUENCE()`though not`LEN(A1)` so that'd've be harder too.